# Using Smarty or Backbone.js for templating javascript

Tags: php, templates, backbone.js, smarty

I have been developing a application for 8 months now that has been utilizing Smarty for PHP templates.

I have had no problems at all with Smarty, and I have started to add more JavaScript interactions for the users on the site.

I was thinking of using backbone.js to template the JavaScript as well.

But another thought came to me, **would it be bad idea to return a smarty template and load it in the div rather then return a json and use backbone.js to format the results?**

Would this slow the application in anyway? What are the benefits (if any) and disadvantages to doing this?

Any thoughts would be great,

Thanks

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Depends on the details (as usual).

Comment: Take a look at [jSmart](http://code.google.com/p/jsmart/), maybe it fits your needs. 
"JavaScript template engine, port of the PHP template engine Smarty to Javascript, lets you use the same templates for PHP and JavaScript, on both server and client-side."

Comment: To elaborate on muistooshort's comment.  Client-side templates (using Backbone) are necessary for single-page apps, optional otherwise.  Likewise, server-side templates (Smarty) are necessary for traditional web applications, optional otherwise.  Using templates on both client and server doesn't *slow* the application, but of course the maintainability of the application takes a hit, as you're duplicating code... right?

Comment: ^^ Wrong, if you are using an MVC environment. Templates can be used in views for both environment if you parse them right. For example, codeigniter has a plugin for both smarty and mustache template engines so you can use the files from either, perhaps in a folder called "templates".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a normal multi-page "web site", users navigate from page to page consuming the site's features.  Backbone however works best with a single-page "web application" model.  With this approach, the only html page loaded is the first one; after that, every "page transition" is actually handled by Backbone's Router, which fakes page transitions dynamically via DOM manipulation.  Each new page's elements are in turn built out of Backbone Views; PHP-generated html is never involved.

And that's why Backbone may not be the best fit for you.  Unless you want to change your PHP code to be purely a server-side API-style structure (which wouldn't really need Smarty), much of Backbone's value is going to be lost.